# Service code not running after application swiped from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

Hi i am using `IntentService` to show notifications to user based on their time set which is stored in `notificationCalendar` variable. I start service using `AlarmManager` and when app is in background(Pressed home button) or running i receive notification but when app is swiped from recent apps no notification is received.

I searched for solutions online for not allowing service to destroy so i return `START_STICKY` in service `onStartCaommand` and in manifest i have added `stopWithTask=false`.

I am testing it on MI phone with API level 22.

Here's my code:

```
private void sendNotification(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

Service class to show notifications:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

public NotificationService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    processStartNotification();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override 
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
} 

private void processStartNotification() {
    // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Habit Time")
            .setContentText("Hey time for your habit")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
  }
}
```

//Manifest file

```
<service
        android:name=".notification.NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Comment: You cannot override `onStartCommand()` in an `IntentService`! If you want a sticky service then you need to extend `Service`, not `IntentService`.

Comment: @DavidWasser i changed it to Service but still not working

Comment: Please post your revised code (update the post with your current implementation) and explain what "doesn't work" in detail.

Comment: @david Wasser i just changed intent service to service and problem is that.....i call sendNotification() method whenever any habit is created by user and set its time but these notifications only show when app is running or in background(pressed home button) but if app is cleared using recent apps button then notifications don't appear

Comment: There are many complaints about this behaveiour in different versions of Android and from different phone manufacturers. Try this: add `android:process=":remote"` to the `<service>` tag in your manifest and see if that helps. This will launch the `Service` into a separate OS process.

Comment: @DavidWasser but other apps such as alarm clock, whatsapp shows the behavior i want

Comment: Maybe you could send an email to the Whatsapp developers and ask them to tell you their secret.

Comment: @DavidWasser i think this is a normal behavior and not that much complicated....everyone in some point in their career must have implemented this fuctinality

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131263/discussion-between-sahil-shokeen-and-david-wasser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some phones, you need to add your app to the list of apps allowed to run in the background. Some Huawei, LG and Xiaomi phones have this. If your app is not in this list, swiping the task from the list of recent tasks will kill any background processes and not restart them.

Look in Settings->Battery->Manage Apps Battery Usage